# Laravel send files to FTP whilst specifying the username and password

Tags: laravel, ftp, storage

So, I've made a script that generates feeds which need to go to specific FTP locations.
I've got the credentials ion my feeds table, but how can I get laravel to use these instead of the default ones from the .env file?

This is what I've got, whcih si fine for a defualt location.

```
$file_ftp = Storage::disk('ftp')->put('{{ $feed->filename }}', $feedData);
```

Just wondered if there was a way to override the ftp credentials inline..

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's the answer to my own question:

```
$config = [
                'host' => 'ftp.server.com',
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password',
                'ssl' => 'true',
                'passive' => 'true',
                'root' => '/',
                'timeout' => 30,
                'ignorePassiveAddress' => 'false'
            ];

            $fs = new Filesystem(new Ftp($config));

            //Upload to FTP location
            $fs->put($feed->filename, Storage::get('/storage/' . $feed->filename));
```